# How to Monitor Specific Memory Address Changes in Multi-threaded C++ Game

Tags: c++, multithreading

We're developing a multi-threaded game in C++, which features approximately 120 running threads. Within our code, a struct `MyStruct` is defined as:

```cpp
struct MyStruct{
 void* ptr01;
 void* ptr02;
};
```

This struct is instantiated tens of thousands of times in one thread. We're experiencing a very elusive and infrequent bug where an unspecified thread writes either 0x01 or 0x02 to the 5th byte of the ptr02 member of a `MyStruct`instance. This issue is so rare and unpredictable that numerous continuous automated playbacks and multiple debuggers working for hundreds of hours have failed to reproduce the bug, making troubleshooting a daunting challenge.

Our principal aim is to identify where these changes to ptr02 are coming from. To that end, we're looking for a solution that can notify or trigger a breakpoint when a certain memory address (in this case, the 5th byte of ptr02 in `MyStruct`) is altered.

To address this issue, we've explored the use of `VirtualProtect` in the Windows environment. However, since `VirtualProtect` operates on pages rather than specific addresses, and we have thousands of `MyStruct` instances, it has resulted in numerous false positives which have made it hard to identify the genuine alterations leading to the bug.

Given these constraints, are there any other techniques or tools we could use to effectively monitor alterations to specific memory addresses in such a scenario? It's worth noting that significant modifications to the structure or threading are not feasible due to the architecture of our game.

We would greatly appreciate any insights or advice that could help us tackle this elusive bug.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

※ One instance of memory state before and after

```
0x10  c0 71 77 10 11 00 00 00 30 44 c3 4c 00 00 00 00
-----------------------------------------------------
0x10  c0 71 77 10 11 00 00 00 30 44 c3 4c 02 00 00 00
```

Comment: "trigger a breakpoint when a certain memory address (in this case, the 5th byte of ptr02 in MyStruct) is altered." Do you mean trigger a breakpoint when the 5th byte of ptr02 in *any of tens of thousands instances of MyStruct* is altered?

Comment: Couldn't you make the members private and only allow access to them via accessors? `void* get_p1(size_t idx) { if(idx == 5) log("accesss to 5"); return ptr01[idx]; }`. Do they really have to be `void*` btw?

Comment: If you want to keep them all together on the same page(s) so you can protect them you could use a pool allocator.

Comment: ¿Have you tried tools like address sanitizer and / or Application Verifier? Also a game with  "approximately 120 running threads", makes little sense. They will interfere with each other fighting for processor time since it is very uncommon to have so many cores on consumer PCs.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI, I dont actually want to trigger a breakpoint, I want to get a callback, notificaiton or anything similar, when the 5th byte of ptr02m in any of thens of thousands instances of MyStructs.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, the members are private and of course they are not void* ptr either. I simplified the struct itself. I will update the question. There is no setter for the members. So it is obvious some other code, is accessing some memory it is not supposed to.

Comment: Aha, I see... AddressSanitizer/UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer could help then and possibly ThreadSanitizer too.

Comment: we are running 7/24 address sanitizer, thread sanitized and undefined b sanitizer and non of them finds any illegal access

Comment: @user7860670, you are definitely right about number of threads being too much. They are not active at all times, we have max 120 threads, and 80 on average. They are not fighting for cpu time so much, threadpool is fine tuned. We have 60 fps on PS5 and 120 on PC no problems.

Comment: What compiler are you using when using UBsan and TSan? You are not using them in the same binary, right?

Comment: @TedLyngmo, thanks for taking an interest in the question. We are using clang for windows and customised clang for ps5. Do you mean we are trying to create a binary using UBSan and TSan at the same time? of course not

Comment: @HasanEmrahSüngü Ok, just had to make sure :)